# How to set click listener in butter knife on views found from a certain view?

Tags: android, butterknife

I have a view instance. From that I am able to bind views using :

```
Butterknife.findById(view,R.id.textUser)
```

### But I also need to set click listener on this user text textview. How to achieve it using Butterknife??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are talking about @OnClick Annotation.

Simple usage:

```
@OnClick(R.id.textUser)
void userClicked(TextView textView){
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: This annotation works well when I am doing something inside a activity.But I am doing the binding in a class which is not an activity, but has a view(Basically I am using separate class for initialising the view elements)

Comment: This is not very elegant to make UI functionality outside an activity. You should avoid doing this tbh.

Comment: @OnClick works well inside an activity. But it is not working in the class which I am using to initialise the views. For eg I have an activity A. I have another class B. I have passed activity A in the constructor of class B and in class B i was using setOnclickListener and findViewById.
This type of structure helps me in proper structuring of my code

Comment: Have you tried using Butterknife.bind(activity,view) and then using @Bind annotation and @OnClick?